# Bootstrap Modal close button not working on smaller screens

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some modals, I'm using an 'x' button on the top right of the screen to close the modal. While the button works on larger devices (when the width is > 768 pixels), I've found that the button doesn't work on smaller devices (such as on mobile).

This is the HTML I use for the close button, which I got directly off the Bootstrap documentation:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span class="close-btn" aria-hidden="true">
        &times;
    </span>
</button>
```

I also added the class `close-btn` to change to font size to 2.5 em to make it larger.

Edit: Here's the full modal:

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span class="close-btn" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Title here.</h2>
                    <hr class="star-primary">

                    <h3 class="text-center">
                        Text here.
                    </h3>

                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding the entire code of the modal as the error might be in the div containing this button.

Comment: Did you include bootstrap.js file ?

Comment: @RidoanSalehNasution Yes, I included it in the `<head>`.

Comment: can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the button tag inside the modal body

```
<div class="modal-body">
                 <button type="button" class="close close-btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span class="" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

                    <h2 class="text-center">Title here.</h2>
                    <hr class="star-primary">

                    <h3 class="text-center">
                        Text here.
                    </h3>

                    <br />
                </div>
```

Here is the codepen link for reference

https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/weBOvy?editors=1100

Hope this Works..

Comment: No, the button still doesn't work on smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

Probably on small screens the button is covered by other elements. Solve it by adding a high z-index:

```
<button type="button" class="close my-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span class="close-btn" aria-hidden="true">
        &times;
    </span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.my-close{
    z-index:999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `position: relative; z-index: 9999` solves the issue:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="position: relative; z-index: 9999">&times;</button>
```

Hope this works.